# Registering a pair of binary masks

Tags: python, simpleitk, image-registration

I'm trying to register a pair of binary masks, not a pair of images.
To explain further, I'm trying to build a model that automatically strips the brain from the head skull. For the better model accuracy, I already have labeled the brain area using ITK-SNAP.
I just wonder if I can do the registration between the binary masks, not the images.
Is there any tool for this purpose?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Masks are simple images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool that can perform registration of binary masks, [platipy](https://github.com/pyplati/platipy).

You can download from pip, but make sure to update pip first as there are some known issues with dependency resolution with older versions of pip.

```
pip install -U pip
pip install platipy
```

This software includes functionality for linear (e.g. rigid, affine) and deformable registration.

Here is a short demo:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

from platipy.imaging.registration import linear_registration

# read in images
bin_mask_1 = sitk.ReadImage("bin_mask_1.nii.gz", sitk.sitkUInt8)
bin_mask_2 = sitk.ReadImage("bin_mask_2.nii.gz", sitk.sitkUInt8)

# perform registration
bin_mask_2_reg, tfm = linear_registration(bin_mask_1, bin_mask_2)
```

The code in platipy is pretty well documented, but raise an issue in the github repository if you need further help!

N.B. There are skull-stripping tools in [FreeSurfer](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/FreeSurferWiki) which you might want to check out.

If you want to apply this transformation to a new image, adapt this code:

```
from platipy.imaging.registration.utils import apply_transform

img_mri = sitk.ReadImage("img_mri.nii.gz")

img_mri_reg = apply_transform(
    input_image=img_mri,
    reference_image=bin_mask_1,
    transform=tfm,
    default_value=0,
    interpolator=sitk.sitkLinear,
)
```

Note that the default value should be modified as appropriate (e.g. -1000 for CT images, usually 0 for MRI) and the interpolator can be changed (e.g. sitk.sitkNearestNeighbor for labels, sitk.sitkLinear or sitk.sitkBSpline for images).

Comment: Thank you!! Just one more question, is the bin_mask_1 fixed image and the bin_mask_2 moving image in this case?

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped feel free to accept. Yes, in this example `bin_mask_1` will be the fixed image.

Comment: As you recommend me platipy, I could successfully execute linear_registration for two binary masks (.nii.gz).

Now I am trying to apply this tfm to the MRI image (also .nii.gz) to see how it goes.

Is there any way that I can apply the tfm information from the binary masks registration to the MRI image?

I've been searching for almost more than 24 hrs and there were no big advancement. Thank you.